# How to call the constructor of the members of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class:

```
public class a {
    
    public int memberA;
    private int memberB;
    
    public a (int i) {
        memberA = i;
        memberB = ...;
    }
}
```

and another one:

```
public class b {
    
    public a[] = new a[10]; // <-- How do I call the constructor of 'a' with a value?
    
    ...
}
```

I tried many things, but nothing works! My app crashes if I don't call the constructor!

Comment: On which element of the array? Also, you forgot to name the array. Supposing it's called `aa` you can do `aa[0] = new a(0); aa[1] = new a(1);` and so on... Or do it with a loop.

Comment: Agree with the above point. The array is just a reference holder, create objects and then put them inside the array.

Comment: You're naming the array ``a`` which is also the class name.

Comment: Yea thats true, but my class is actually called different, this is just for showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a `for` loop to instantiate each element of the array.

```
public class b {
    public a[] arr = new a[10];
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = new a(/*some value*/);
    }
}
```

As an aside, always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of the classes should be `A` and `B` instead of `a` and `b`. Better if you use self-descriptive names.

Comment: @Cosemuckel No problem.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you might be able to use functional operators, which might be clearer in this case.

Comment: I don't think you need to use a scope here, it can sometimes clarify the stages of your code, but I think it just obfuscates the code here.

Comment: @Quadslab This is an instance initializer.

Comment: How about switching to uppercase for class name per Java naming convention?

Comment: @Unmitigated Oh, I think I just intuitively read `a` as a method, because of the camel case.